# Poner botones al fondo del contenedor

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de poner tres botones abajo de todo del div de color rojo.
Traté usando `position:relative bottom:0px;` pero no funciona.

```css
body{

  text-align:center;

}

input{

    max-width:15%;

}

.pomodoro{

    background:#e54444;
    height:200px;
    color:white;

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-2">

            <h2>Pomodoro Timer</h2>

        </div>

       <div class="col-xs-2">

           <img class="img-responsive"src="http://pomodoro.trevorlandau.net/images/pom.png" align="right" height="150" width="150"/>

       </div>

    </div>  

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"> 

            <h4>Work Time</h4>
            <input id="workT"type="number" min=1 name="work-time" value=25>

        </div>  

     <div class="restTime col-xs-6 text-left">

         <h4>Rest Time</h4>
         <input id="restT" type="number" min=1 name="res-time" value=5>
     </div> 


    </div>  
    <div class="pomodoro"> 

        <div class="action"></div>
        <div class="time"></div>

        <button id="startButton"class="btn btn-default">Start</button>  
        <button id="continueButton"class="btn btn-default">Continue</button>
        <button id="stopButton"class="btn btn-default">Stop</button>


    </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como recomendación, te sugiero que agrupes tus botones dentro de otro div, en este caso, yo lo he llamado `contenedor` (porque contiene a los botones).

Después, tendrás que asignarle la posición relativa al div rojo mediante `position: relative` y posición absoluta al contenedor que acabamos de crear con `position: absolute` para que el contenedor esté posicionado en relación a su elemento con `position: relative` más cercano, en este caso, el div rojo.

Por último, si quieres centrar tu `#contenedor` dentro del div rojo puedes usar `left: 0` y `right: 0` para que el `#contenedor` aparezca centrado horizontalmente dentro del div rojo.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
body{
  text-align:center;
}

input{
    max-width:15%;
}

.pomodoro{
    position: relative;
    background:#e54444;
    height:200px;
    color:white;
}

#contenedor{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-2">
            <h2>Pomodoro Timer</h2>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2">
           <img class="img-responsive"src="http://pomodoro.trevorlandau.net/images/pom.png" align="right" height="150" width="150"/>
       </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right"> 
            <h4>Work Time</h4>
            <input id="workT"type="number" min=1 name="work-time" value=25>
        </div>  
     <div class="restTime col-xs-6 text-left">
         <h4>Rest Time</h4>
         <input id="restT" type="number" min=1 name="res-time" value=5>
     </div> 
    </div>  
  
    <div class="pomodoro"> 
        <div class="action"></div>
        <div class="time"></div>
        <div id="contenedor">
          <button id="startButton"class="btn btn-default">Start</button>  
          <button id="continueButton"class="btn btn-default">Continue</button>
          <button id="stopButton"class="btn btn-default">Stop</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @aldanux Corregido. ¡Gracias por el apunte!